# edit context menu in browser

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I tried to `edit` context menu in `web browser`. I know the way how to edit in windows application but my need is same thing in web browser, means when user right click on web browser the context menu display and having content  like `save link`, `bookmark link`, `open link in new tab`....e.t.c.

I tried to find a solution but still didn't get any solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't do that by any server-side tecnology. The only way is overriding default browser's context menu by your own custom javasctipt-menu or other client-side technic. Most of javascript UI libraries contains a context menu, for example [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/menu/contextmenu.html) or [JQuery plugin](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/contextmenu/).